# Symfony Custom Error Page By Overriding ExceptionController

Tags: symfony, exception, error-handling, custom-error-pages

what I am trying to do is to have custom error page, not only will they be extending the base layout but also I want extra up selling content in those pages too so changing templates only is not an option

regardless of the reason (404 Not Found or just missing variable) I would like to show my template and my content instead

I have spent hours trying to get this going with no luck

```
app/console --version
Symfony version 2.5.6 - app/dev/debug
```

I tried some resources, but couldn't get it working. The name a few:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

I'm running in dev with no debug, see `app_dev.php` below:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', false);
```

following the tutorials i got these extra bits

`app/config/config.yml`

```
twig:
    exception_controller:  SomethingAppBundle:Exception:show
```

in my bundle

```
<?php

namespace Something\AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ExceptionController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction( FlattenException $error, DebugLoggerInterface $debug)
    {
        print_r($error);
    }

}
```

but my error controller does not get executed,

I am on purpose causing error by trying to echo undefined variable in different controller, since it should handle error from entire application

Comment: *"some useless resources I tried, in fact I tried many more but from the frustration I am only going to mention these two, after all its the "documentation" right, despite nothing ever worked from there, hate to be bragging but WTFPOS Documentation"*. I know you're frustrated, but please don't blame others for it. If this is your honest opinion, please show me code examples that aren't working for you and we'll fix them. Just like we did for all other doc bugs in the past 3 years

Comment: sorry, but the code above should have worked for "Replacing the Default ExceptionController" section

Comment: @tomhre Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

**At the beginning you need to create action in the controller:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class ErrorController extends Controller
{
    
    public function notFoundAction()
    {
        return $this->render('error/404.html.twig');
    }
}
```

**Then you need to create a Listener:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class NotFoundHttpExceptionListener
{
    private $controller_resolver;
    private $request_stack;
    private $http_kernel;

    public function __construct($controller_resolver, $request_stack, $http_kernel)
    {
        $this->controller_resolver = $controller_resolver;
        $this->request_stack = $request_stack;
        $this->http_kernel = $http_kernel;
    }
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {

        if ($event->getException() instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

            $request = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request();
            $request->attributes->set('_controller', 'AppBundle:Error:notFound');
            $controller = $this->controller_resolver->getController($request);

            $path['_controller'] = $controller;
            $subRequest = $this->request_stack->getCurrentRequest()->duplicate(array(), null, $path);

            $event->setResponse($this->http_kernel->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST)); // Simulating "forward" in order to preserve the "Not Found URL"

        }
    }
}
```

**Now register the service:**

```
#AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.notFoundHttpException:
            class: AppBundle\EventListener\NotFoundHttpExceptionListener
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException, priority: -10 }
            arguments: [ @controller_resolver, @request_stack, @http_kernel ]
```

*Not tested this, but rather it should work;)*

## EDIT:

**Tested, it works. On the rendered page, you have a session, so you have access to app.user, his cart, and other matters related to the session.**

Comment: hi Pawel, the code above is working and I have changed it to handle other that not found exceptions, thanks. But it is not the solution I looked for , sorry, upvoted but will not accept I'm afraid. I wanted to do it by "Replacing the Default ExceptionController" since I hoped I can avoid subrequests and extra service

Comment: Hi @tomhre! I think that: If you want to have a session on the rendered page 404 it will not be possible by overriding ExceptionController. Symfony routing component is invoked before the security component. If the router does not find the path throws an error without user data and **extra up selling content**. In the above solution I send an additional request that is marked as the Master Request.

Comment: "Replacing the Default ExceptionController"
If you need a little more flexibility beyond just overriding the template, then you can change the controller that renders the error page. For example, you might need to pass some additional variables into your template. - Sounds to me like I can have extra content in there, the problem I have is that the twig config works and redirects me to homepage on error if I change it to Homepage:index but as long as it's Error:index goes crazy

Comment: and on top of it your solution does not pay attention to environment so in dev mode i lost all debug

Comment: In dev mode profiler works fine on rendered page. You still have exception in the "ghost" tab :)